# How to find a string key in a map that does not match a regexp?

Tags: java, regex

I simply need a map that has all the keys and values that do not match a certain regexp. Is there an easy way to negate find() or matches() in Java?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)"+dateFormatter.format(Date.from(now))+"(.*)");

Map<String, Writer> toBeClosed = orcWriterMap.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(entry -> pattern.matcher(entry.getKey()).find())
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Use `.split("pattern")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you might transform Pattern to predicate.
Example:

```
Predicate<String> predicate = pattern.asPredicate().negate();
```

Then

```
filter(entry -> predicate.test(entry.getKey())
```

Comment: This approach is really interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Use not (`!`)

```
.filter(entry -> ! pattern.matcher(entry.getKey()).find())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can negate the Mather `matches()` function.

```
.filter(entry -> !pattern.matcher(entry.getKey()).matches())
```

In this case, using the matches() function is better than using the find() function, because we're not dealing with multiple subsequences.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following part of your code:

```
filter(entry -> pattern.matcher(entry.getKey()).find())
```

You filter here the source stream.
For each source *entry* you check whether the key included in this entry
has a match somewhere in the pattern.

So, if you want to get a map including keys that **do not match** the pattern,
then just negate the filter condition:

```
filter(entry -> !pattern.matcher(entry.getKey()).find())
```

Note the exclamation char - negation operator.